# VSCode how do two developers compile code on their own PC?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compilation

I'm using VSCode to make a Java game with my friend. We are using the java.awt libraries. We are using live share so we can both work on the code, but when we compile the game window only shows up for me (the host) and not him. How do we go about working on this game together?

If it's not clear what I'm asking, please ask.

Comment: You can use Git for version control, more can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into GitHub. 
You can upload your code from VSCode to a repository on GitHub that you and your friend can both access.
It's a version control system, so you can both work separately without worrying about overwriting each other's work.\GitHub and VSC both have lots of good tutorials to get you started.

Comment: Yea.  But I would generalize that to *any* distributed version control system that has decent VSCode plumbing available.

Comment: Absolutely. I find GitHub to be pretty accessible first step to getting into version control, but yeah, any would work.